# AWS Ruby SDK , check a key exists always gives 'false'

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In AWS S3, I have a bucket named `my-bucket`, I am using [AWS Ruby SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/) to access my bucket.

under `my-bucket` I have the following directory structure in S3 (I know it is not called "directory" in S3, but just to show the idea):

```
my-bucket/
    customers/
         products/
              - data1.txt
              - data2.txt
              ...
```

I want to check does `my-bucket/customers/products` exist with AWS Ruby SDK, I tried the following code:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket("my-bucket")
result = bucket.object("customers/products").exists?
```

But the `result` gives `false`, even though I do have that directory in S3, where am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because "customers/products" doesn't exist as an object. It is just a prefix for some objects that do exist. You stated:

> I know it is not called "directory" in S3

However it's more than just a different term for directories in S3. Directories (or folders) don't exist in S3 at all. There are just objects with keys. It's like a single flat directory, where your filenames can have slash characters in them.

Most S3 browsing applications will interpret slashes in key names as "directories" and display objects in a hierarchical fashion like a filesystem  for convenience sake, but those directories/folders don't actually exist in S3.

As pointed out in the other answer, your best bet is to check if any objects exist that contain that prefix.

Comment: `Object` means the object contained inside `customers/products` like `data.txt`?

Comment: Object means file, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use
`bucket.objects.with_prefix("customers/products").any?`

Comment: undefined method `any?`

Comment: Also as per the aws docs, for referencing a bucket use bucket = s3.buckets['bucket-name']

Comment: full error ` undefined method `any?' for #<Aws::S3::Object:0x007f846d403960> (NoMethodError)
`

Comment: from the error it looks like you are not getting <AWS::S3::ObjectCollection> but a single object and that is why any? is throwing no method error. Try exists? in that case. Also did you try referencing the bucket as the comment above

Answer (score 0):

In **Ruby sdk V2** the method `with_prefix` is not defined:

given an object with key like: **dir1/dir2/object.jpg**

try something like the following

```
bucket.objects(prefix: 'dir1/dir2').any?
```

or directly check for object existence

```
bucket.object('dir1/dir2/object.jpg').exists?
```